# Unable to run 2 sudo commands without asking password from script

Tags: sudo, i3

I want pacman to check for updates on system startup without asking me for password. I created a script `~/bin/startup` which is executed through `~/.config/i3/config`.

In `~/.config/i3/config`:

`exec_always --no-startup-id $HOME/bin/startup`

In `~/bin/startup` I have this line: 
`termite -e 'sudo pacman -Syu ; sudo pacman -Fy'`. 

And in `/etc/sudoers` I added at the end of the file: 

`dovaogedot ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pacman -Syu, /usr/bin/pacman -Fy`

If I launch the script from terminal: 
`$ ~/bin/startup`

it doesn't ask for password and performs check for updates. But when I restart i3 or reboot my PC it does ask for password and after I type it it just closes termite's window without executing pacman's commands.

But if I use only one pacman command in my script (i.e. without `-Fy`) it works as intended. Can somebody explain to me this behavior?

Comment: Use a system startup script rather than a user login script. It's then going to run as root and none of this sudo stuff is necessary.

Comment: I guess it's a syntax issue. What about `dovaogedot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`?